# load a csv file into d3 without sending to server

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

is there anyway to load csv data into d3.csv without sending it to server? I'm trying to use a dataURI but it's not working...

I have a form that a user can choose a csv file from their computer.

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

This leads to the readURL function which creates a dataURI from that file.

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#file_url')
            .attr('data-file-url', f.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Then I have a script to steal that dataURI from the #file_url div and enter it into d3.csv:

```
var address = $('#file_url').attr('data-file-url');
d3.csv(address,function(csv){
    do stuff with that csv
}
```

Problem is I'm getting a cross-origin error.

Comment: Have you tried reading the file into a string and parsing using [`d3.csv.parse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-parse)?

Comment: Trying that right now. What's the proper way to parse the csv file into a string? Right now javascript only reads the first line of the file as a string and the rest triggers an error. I think it's a multiline problem.

Comment: You should read the file as-is, without any conversions. If you're unsuccessful using `d3.csv.parse()`, you could try `parseRows()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File API](http://caniuse.com/fileapi), but is not supported a close browsers especially IE. For more check [this](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/filereader.md.html)

Comment: Is that different from what I was doing?